# Aliases not available when using sudo

Tags: sudo, alias

I was playing around with aliases today and I noticed that aliases don't seem to be available whilst using `sudo`:

```
danny@kaon:~$ alias
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'

danny@kaon:~$ ll -d /
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 2011-01-06 20:29 //

danny@kaon:~$ sudo -i
root@kaon:~# ll -d /
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 2011-01-06 20:29 //
root@kaon:~# exit
logout

danny@kaon:~$ sudo ll -d /
sudo: ll: command not found
```

Is there any reason why you cannot use aliases whilst using `sudo`?

Comment: Did you declare those alias in .bashrc on /root/

Comment: @LucianoFacchinelli: `/root/.bashrc` does not get read when running a command through sudo.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/61321/how-to-pass-alias-through-sudo

Comment: @Flimm: What about `sudo -i`?

Answer (score 386, accepted):

Add the following line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias sudo='sudo '
```

From the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases):

> Aliases allow a string to be substituted for a word when it is used as the first word of a simple command. The shell maintains a list of aliases that may be set and unset with the alias and unalias builtin commands.
>
> **The first word of each simple command, if unquoted, is checked to see if it has an alias**. If so, that word is replaced by the text of the alias. The characters ‘/’, ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘=’ and any of the shell metacharacters or quoting characters listed above may not appear in an alias name. The replacement text may contain any valid shell input, including shell metacharacters. The first word of the replacement text is tested for aliases, but a word that is identical to an alias being expanded is not expanded a second time. This means that one may alias ls to "ls -F", for instance, and Bash does not try to recursively expand the replacement text. **If the last character of the alias value is a space or tab character, then the next command word following the alias is also checked for alias expansion**.

<sup>(Emphasis mine).</sup>
Bash only checks the first word of a command for an alias, any words after that are not checked. That means in a command like `sudo ll`, only the first word (`sudo`) is checked by bash for an alias, `ll` is ignored. We can tell bash to check the next word after the alias (i.e `sudo`) by adding a space to the end of the alias value.

Comment: Pretty nice solution.

Comment: So basically the issue boils down to the fact that sudo is simply programmed in such a way that it does not check alias's therefore ll is not found?

Comment: @DannyRoberts See my updated answer.

Comment: The emphasized quote doesn't show up too well with askubuntu.com's current styling. For the curious, here is the key line: "*If the last character of the alias value is a space or tab character, then the next command word following the alias is also checked for alias expansion.*"

Comment: Reading the documentation obviously benefits a whole lot :-)

Comment: Will this break if I use a sudo flag, e.g. `sudo -H ll`?

Comment: @mehaase Yes, I tried and it breaks.

Comment: This doesn't work in this scenario: `sudo su - anotheruser -s /bin/bash -c 'll'` -- anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: don't forget to `source ~/.bashrc` otherwise it doesn't load up

Comment: This is looks like a magic.

Comment: This works (Ubuntu-MATE 20.x) for direct aliases. It does not work for `alias ll='_ll'` and `_ll` being a function in bashrc...

Comment: This works for aliases, but not functions.

Comment: I love it! This solution is very elegant and really useful. However, with great power comes great responsibility! By introducing such alias into the system, one makes it very easy to accidentally misuse an alias in the name of the superuser. Therefore, the user should be even more cautious of their aliases!

Comment: @MarkE.Haase We need to create a separate alias for sudo with a flag, just make sure there's a blank space after the flag. So for `sudo -H` we could use `alias sudoh="sudo -H "` or for `sudo -i` we could use `sudoi="sudo -i "` etc.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a Bash function for it that shadows `sudo`.

It checks whether I have an alias for the given command and runs the aliased command instead of the literal one with `sudo` in that case.

Here is my function as one-liner:

```bsh
sudo() { if alias "$1" &> /dev/null ; then $(type "$1" | sed -E 's/^.*`(.*).$/\1/') "${@:2}" ; else command sudo $@ ; fi }
```

Or nicely formatted:

```bsh
sudo() { 
    if alias "$1" &> /dev/null ; then 
        $(type "$1" | sed -E 's/^.*`(.*).$/\1/') "${@:2}"
    else 
        command sudo "$@"
    fi 
}
```

You can append it to your `.bashrc` file, don't forget to source it or restart your terminal session afterwards to apply the changes though.

Comment: It would be wonderful if this would also work for sudo -H ll.

Answer (score 4):

The aliases are user specific - you need to define them in `/root/.bashrc`

Comment: They are already under /root/.bashrc so that's not an issue

Comment: This answer would only be correct for the situation when you're running the shell itself as root, as with `sudo  -s` or `sudo -i` (and *only* if run by itself to get a root shell, *not* with the `sudo -s command...` or `sudo -i command...` forms) or `sudo bash` or `sudo su`, or the situation where you've enabled root logins and have a root shell that way. When a non-root user runs `sudo command...` from their own shell, alias expansion is done by their own non-root shell. `sudo` doesn't itself expand aliases, so *as applied to the situation described in the question*, this answer is incorrect.

Comment: I confirm @kemra102: I do have my root aliases in place. `su    ll` not a problem. `sudo ll` failures.

Answer (score 4):

@Alvins answer is the shortest one. No doubt! :-)

However I thought of a command line solution to **execute an aliased command in sudo** where there is no need to redefine `sudo` with an `alias` command.

Here is my proposal for those to whom it may interest:

### Solution

```
type -a <YOUR COMMAND HERE> | grep -o -P "(?<=\`).*(?=')" | xargs sudo
```

### Example

In the case of the `ll` command

```
type -a ll | grep -o -P "(?<=\`).*(?=')" | xargs sudo
```

### Explanation

when you have an alias (such as: `ll`) the command `type -a` returns the aliased expression:

```
$type -a ll
ll is aliased to `ls -l'
```

with `grep` you select the text between the accent ` and apostrophe ' in that case `ls -l`

And `xargs` executes the selected text `ls -l` as parameter of `sudo`.

Yes,  a bit longer but **completely clean** ;-) No need to redefine `sudo` as alias.

Comment: Might be simpler if you used the `alias` builtin, since its output is cleaner. `alias ll` outputs `alias ll='ls -ahlF'`.

Comment: Here's the version incorporating @muru's suggestion: `alias ll | sed "s/.*'\(.*\)'.*/\1/g" | xargs sudo`.

Comment: I think the point of the original question was to save work by not having to `sudo -i` first, to run the aliased command, but doing it straight away.
Having such a complex command defeats that. You could just do the former, and be much quicker.

Comment: Which answer was by @Alvins? I can't find it and it isn't refernced.

Answer (score 2):

I have another nice solution, that adds a bit of trust too:

**Use bash completion to automatically replace words behind `sudo` with their aliases when pressing tab.**

Save this as `/etc/bash_completion.d/sudo-alias.bashcomp`, and it should automatically be loaded at interactive shell startup:

```bsh
_comp_sudo_alias() { from="$2"; COMPREPLY=()
  if [[ $COMP_CWORD == 1 ]]; then
    COMPREPLY=( "$( alias -p | grep "^ *alias $from=" | sed -r "s/^ *alias [^=]+='(.*)'$/\1/" )" )
    return 0
  fi
  return 1
}
complete -o bashdefault -o default -F _comp_sudo_alias sudo
```

Then log in to a new terminal, and you should be good to go.

Comment: There's a way to get a list of aliases, especially meant for completion: `compgen -a`

Comment: @muru: Thanks, but in this case I need the values, not the keys. So what the alias that was entered will be replaced with. You type the alias, (like in `sudo ll`), press [TAB ↹], and the script finds `ll` in the list of alias assignments , cuts out what it is assigned to it, and inserts that. (So you’d get e.g. `sudo ls -lahvF --color=auto --time-style=long-iso`.)

Answer (score 2):

[@WinEunuuchs2Unix](https://askubuntu.com/a/853332/830570): `$PWD` expands to the "present working directory". I think you want `$HOME`.

Also, for most situations, it's probably best to have a separate root .bashrc file. In fact, I'd make it a real file in `/root`, soft link to it in the user's home directory (e.g., `.bashrc_root`), and source it from the user's `.bashrc` file. If at some later time this privileged user account is no longer present, the root `.bashrc` file is still available for other users.

Answer (score 1):

If you type `sudo -i` and elevate to a sudo prompt (`#`) you won't have the aliases or functions you like to use.

To utilize your aliases and functions at the `#` prompt, use:

```
sudo cp "$HOME"/.bashrc /root/.bashrc
```

Where "$HOME" is expanded into "/home/YOUR_USER_NAME"

Comment: @DKBose Thanks for catching that for me :)

Comment: Attention! This overwrites your  `/root/.bashrc` (obv.) - and thus might add a whole bunch of other side effects.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different solution whereby you do not need to add `sudo` as an alias. I run Linux Mint 17.3 but it should be pretty similar to Ubuntu.

When you are root, then the `.profile` is run from its home directory. If you do not know what the home directory under root is, then you can check with:

```
sudo su
echo $HOME
```

As you can see, the home of `root` is `/root/`. Check its contents:

```
cd $HOME
ls -al
```

There should be a `.profile` file. Open the file and add the following lines:

```
if [ "$BASH" ]; then
    if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases];then
        . ~/.bash_aliases 
    fi
fi
```

Basically, what this bash script does is to check for a file called `.bash_aliases`. If the files is present, it executes the file.

Save the `.profile` file and create your aliases in `.bash_aliases`. If you already have the aliases file ready, then copy the file to this location

Re-launch the terminal and you are good to go!

Comment: You can just symlink your aliases for root user with `sudo ln -s /home/$(whoami)/.bash_aliases /root/.bash_aliases` just to keep a single version. However, this answer only enables aliases if you are within root shell (i.e. `sudo -i`), but not if you invoke a command with `sudo yourownalias`. This is because Bash does not load root profile when `sudo command` is invoked.