# alias with parameters

Tags: shortcut-keys, sudo, alias

I was recently starting to setup my usual alias. I ended up needing to pass more information than my alias originally needed

```
$ alias runserver = 'python manage.py runserver'
$ runserver 80  // turns out you need sudo
$ sudo runserver 80
$ sudo: runserver: command not found
```

Now as I was writing this i realized maybe the alias isn't set for root. Could that be it?

If not, could someone explain why this doesn't work.

Please and thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: the body of this question is a duplicate of [Aliases not available when using sudo](https://askubuntu.com/q/22037/6969).

---

In the [above question](https://askubuntu.com/q/22037/6969), they solved the sudo problem by aliasing sudo too:

```
alias sudo='sudo '
```

Note that the title is misleading, "alias with parameter" would be a function. Assuming that your `runserver` alias would accept a single argument, the port:

```
runserver(){ python manage.py runserver $1;}
```

If `runserver` accepts an unknown amount of parameters, pass all parameters using:

```
runserver(){ python manage.py runserver "$@";}
```

For the latter syntax, consult the [bash manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/bash.1.html).

Comment: mm, yes, I always forget that hack.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` doesn't see aliases in the invoking shell.  Aliases in `.bashrc` will show up with `sudo -s` or `sudo -i`; the former is your `.bashrc`, the latter for `root`'s.

In any case, wouldn't the easier way be `alias runserver='sudo python manage.py runserver'`?

Comment: I dont always want to run it as root.