# Independence between sudo and the instruction it receives as an argument

Tags: command-line, sudo, colors, ls

[image]

I don't understand why the directory dir1 isn't shown with the same colour.
Although this may look unimportant, it seems to me that this is a violation of the so oftenly mentioned principle of independence in computing(I have professors who mention it during each lecture).

I know that 'ls' is an argument of 'sudo', but shouldn't 'sudo' just change privileges and then NOT interfere in ANY way with the instruction it receives as an argument?

Comment: Here's an answer for your question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22037/aliases-not-available-when-using-sudo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This discrepancy comes from a simple option to `ls` nothing else.

In fact your `ls` is aliased to `ls --color=auto`. To see it try in terminal,

```
type ls
```

That is why you have colored outputs. But when you use `sudo ls` it uses `/bin/ls` which does not have the color option with it. So it fails to show colored outputs.

If you try `/bin/ls` you also will have color less output. Or try `sudo ls --color=auto` which should give you color.

Comment: Moreover, `sudo` will "clean" a lot of environment variables for sake of security. Try `env` and `sudo env` and see the difference. The rationale is that the privileged commands must run in a consistent way, independently from what you have set in the profiles for your shell.

Answer (score 0):

I **believe** this is because your user `octavian` and the elevation of that user's permissions happens in two different shells.

Ubuntu by default uses `bash` as he shell for users.  When you run commands through `sudo`, the shell changes to `sh`.

Here is a screenshot demonstrating the different shells.

You can see the first time I run `ls`, I'm in the bash shell.  You can tell because the prompt notes my username, hostname, and current directory.

When I switch to `sh`, the prompt changes as it's a completely different shell with different features.

[image]

There are tons of different shells available, all with different features, prompts, and customization options.  One of the most customizable shell is `zsh`.