# Text on Desktop that can be copied but not modified

Tags: text, copy

I have some code that I use all the time in the terminal, so I would like to have it on the Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS desktop. I want to be able to copy it from the desktop but not be able to modify it from the desktop (in order to not change it by mistake).

Is there a extension? Can I write some code that can do it and if yes where should I put it?

Below you can see what I want to do:
[image]

Comment: Why not look into something like Autokey which will let you avoid the copy/paste step?

Comment: That sounds like you might find a [clipboard manager](https://www.tecmint.com/best-clipboard-managers-for-linux/) useful. Some IDE's / code editors even have it built in (e.g. as "snippets").

Comment: Can you please provide samples of the code you want to paste?

Comment: @JonasCz I didn't know about clipboard managers but and as far as I understood you have to have a running software and I don't want that just for a line of text.

Comment: @DK Bose It is just two lines that initiate a VPN connection, a cd command and one more.

Comment: And you don't want to create aliases or functions for them?

Comment: Not yet familiar with the term aliases. I think I will do a clickable program at the end

Comment: For `alias`, see https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases and, if you need `sudo`, https://askubuntu.com/questions/22037/aliases-not-available-when-using-sudo

Comment: ooo thank you very much @DKBose ! It works perfect for me