# Sudo aliased to please; how do i make please see aliases?

Tags: bash, bashrc, alias

I made sudo see aliases with `alias sudo='sudo '`. I aliased sudo to please (`alias please=sudo`), and with please it didn't worked: `alias please='please '`. please still didn't see my aliases.
How to make please see aliases?

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Probably you would want to ask - is it possible to use an `alias` within another `alias`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd make `please` "see" aliases in the same way that you made `sudo` see aliases: `alias please='sudo '`

Ex.

```
$ type la
la is aliased to `ls -A'

$ alias please='sudo '

$ please la /root
[sudo] password for steeldriver:
.bash_history  .bashrc  .lesshst  .local  .motd_shown  .profile  .viminfo  trace.out
```

See also

- [Aliases not available when using sudo](https://askubuntu.com/a/22043/178692)

Answer (score 0):

Sudo is an external program, so it can only run programs that are in the PATH var, but aliases are only in bash meaning that when you make a alias bash goes a look at the alias and runs it.