# How to run an alias inside an alias in fish?

Tags: alias, configure, fish

I aliased `sudo` to `please` [with a space](https://askubuntu.com/a/22043/1165986):

```
$ alias please='sudo '
$ please ll
```

I have tried this in Fish, but it doesn't work:

```
$ alias please='sudo '
$ please ll
sudo: ll: command not found
```

Comment: "Aliases" in fish are [actually functions](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/4320), abbreviations are closer to aliases in bash. I don't think this behaviour is possible for either, though. You might make binding instead, but those are awkward too.

Comment: @muru Right - It would be nice if *either* abbreviations or aliases/functions worked for the `sudo` case, but (a) aliases are tied to the *user* config, and (b) we'll need [global abbreviations](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/5003) (not yet implemented) for it to work with `abbr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here isn't nested aliases.  That in itself will *work*, although (as @muru points out in the comments) somewhat differently than Bash.  For instance:

```
$ alias a ls
$ alias b type
$ b a
a is a function with definition
# Defined via `source`
function a --wraps=ls --description 'alias a ls'
  ls $argv; 
end
```

The problem with `sudo` in a Fish alias is twofold:

- First, an alias is defined for your user, but when you `sudo`, you aren't "your user" any more.  The fish configuration inside `sudo` is that of the `root` user.  Unfortunately, the elegant Bash solution of appending a "space" doesn't work for Fish.
- The Bash "trailing space" workaround of expanding the second alias before passing it to the first, via `alias please='sudo '` isn't available in Fish.  For instance, in the preceding example, in Bash you could use `alias b='type '` to force expansion of `a` to `ls` and run the `type` command on the *result* rather than the *alias*.

  This is, IMHO, definitely one area where Bash has a (much) cleaner solution than Fish.

There are a few possible workarounds for Fish, but I think they are all rather "hacky", even my own.

First, as I mention in [this Stack Overflow answer], you can define your `sudo` alias as follows:

```
function please --wraps=sudo --description 'alias please sudo'
    if functions -q -- "$argv[1]"
        set cmdline (
            for arg in $argv
                printf "\"%s\" " $arg
            end
        )
        set -x function_src (string join "\n" (string escape --style=var (functions "$argv[1]")))
        set argv fish -c 'string unescape --style=var (string split "\n" $function_src) | source; '$cmdline
        command sudo -E $argv
    else
        command sudo $argv
    end
end
```

It would probably take me a bit to remember exactly how I arrived at that, which is why I left a commented version with the explanation [here](https://gist.github.com/NotTheDr01ds/6357e48b511735c42b94c4cc081ac5dc).

While you might consider defining the alias in the root user's Fish config, note that `sudo` only runs external commands, so it still won't run aliases this way, unless you ask a *new* `fish` process to run it.  E.g.:

```
$ sudo -s
$ alias -s ll "ls -l"
funcsave: wrote /root/.config/fish/functions/ll.fish
$ exit # back to normal user
$ sudo fish -c "ll"
$ sudo ll
sudo: ll: command not found
$ sudo fish -c "ll -n /"
total 1436
lrwxrwxrwx   1 0 0       7 Apr 23  2020 bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 0 0    4096 Apr 23  2020 boot
...
```

Comment: Interesting, and the `please` function here might be what OP needs. But the initial example I think isn't quite what's expected. If I were expecting the bash behaviour, taking `alias a='ls '` `alias b='type '`, the output should be `ls is /usr/bin/ls`. The behaviour you show would be that of `alias b=type`, for which bash would say ``a is aliased to `ls '``, like `fish` here says `a is a function...`.

Comment: @muru Great point - Edited to try to clarify that.  Thanks!