# XAMPP is not working on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: command-line, php, lamp, xampp, alias

I have been using XAMPP to work on personnal project using PHP.
XAMPP used to work before when I first installed it but now there seems to be an issue that I can't seem to resolve.
Here's what happens:

- I have aliases for my lampp commands and whenever I run it as a normal user, it asks me to be root.
- Then when I add sudo before the command to become root, it tells me there is no such command.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks,
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have answered your own question, as part of the question itself.

You write: *"I have aliases for my lampp commands ..."*.

Aliases normally **do not** work when using `sudo`, which is explained in [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22037/aliases-not-available-when-using-sudo).

For aliases to work with sudo, you have to add the "hack": `alias sudo='sudo '`

Secondly, if you look at the official [FAQ for XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_linux.html), it's pretty clear that the command needed to run is: `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`.

I reckon the issue here is that the executable is not in the `$PATH` as it normally would, so you basically have 3 options:

1. Add `/opt/lampp` to your `$PATH` (and also for `root` for it to work with `sudo`)
2. Make your aliases work under `sudo`
3. Use the full path `/opt/lampp/lampp` as indicated in the FAQ

Either option should work out in the end.

Comment: Yep that's it. Geez I am such an idiot sometimes. Thank you very much