# How to give docker-compose alias to the new docker compose (v2) command?

Tags: docker, alias

I noticed that docker-compose 1.x is gently being dropped in favor of the new v2:
https://www.docker.com/blog/announcing-compose-v2-general-availability/

So I then removed my `docker-compose` v1.x command (I think it was the way to go, but I cannot find the old [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) on how to install/uninstall docker-compose anymore):

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Then I installed the new version according to the [doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/):

```
$ sudo apt-get install docker-compose-plugin
```

and voilà:

```
$ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.5.0
```

But all my scripts which used to call `docker-compose` (with a dash) are no more working. Obviously.

Hence my question; how could I alias the new compose command to `docker-compose`?

Is it sufficient to add this line to by `.bashrc` file?

```
$ echo "alias docker-compose='docker compose'" >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Didn't the alias work as intended?

Answer (score 6):

The absolute easiest solution is to make an alias, like you state in your question:

```
alias docker-compose='docker compose'
```

This will work without any issue.

Also, I would recommend installing Docker Compose using the `apt` package `docker-compose-plugin`, and not by manually installing with `curl`, unless you have a very good reason to do so.

By installing with `apt` (which is the recommended way on Ubuntu), you ensure that you can update Docker Compose automatically with new Docker releases using `apt upgrade` or even with unattended upgrades.

Answer (score 6):

Adding an alias to `.bashrc` will work for most cases, but for some scripts may not work.

IMHO creating a small script named `docker-compose` to your `PATH` that just passes arguments to `docker compose` is a better way to solve the problem.

This answer might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72187587/11418220

Comment: You're 100% correct than in some edge cases, a function might be more versatile than an alias (most notably if the script attempts to execute with sudo, and you haven't implemented a [sudo/alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22037/aliases-not-available-when-using-sudo) workaround) - upvoted!

Comment: Thanks for upvote @ArturMeinild I don'e have enough reputation to write comment yet, but I wanted to mention that using `docker-compose-plugin` is better than `docker-compose` as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It was not 100% clear to me but there are two ways to install compose on the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/):

1. the former, by `apt install docker-compose-plugin`
2. a second way (user either the first way or the second, but not both) by manually downloading the binary with `curl` but it misses some details I think, especially the newly created folder is not in the default `path`. Here's how I proceeded to install it globally (i.e. in `/usr/local/...`):

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge docker-compose-plugin

$ sudo su

# DOCKER_CONFIG_CLI="/usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins"

# mkdir -p $DOCKER_CONFIG_CLI

# curl -SL https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.5.0/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 -o $DOCKER_CONFIG_CLI/docker-compose

# chmod +x $DOCKER_CONFIG_CLI/docker-compose

# cd /usr/local/bin

# mv docker-compose docker-compose_v1 # only if you had a previous docker-compose version!

# ln -s /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

# exit

$ which docker-compose
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

or in one shot:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

apt-get update \
&& apt-get remove --purge docker-compose-plugin \
&& DOCKER_CONFIG_CLI="/usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins" \
&& mkdir -p $DOCKER_CONFIG_CLI \
&& curl -SL https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.5.0/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 -o $DOCKER_CONFIG_CLI/docker-compose \
&& chmod +x $DOCKER_CONFIG_CLI/docker-compose \
&& cd /usr/local/bin \
&& mv docker-compose docker-compose_v1 \
&& ln -s /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose \
&& which docker-compose
```

Then you got the two ways of calling it, the transition is smoother:

```
$ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.5.0
```

```
$ docker-compose --version
# or: docker-compose version
Docker Compose version v2.5.0
```

Comment: This seems like an extremely hacky and avant-garde solution, and I fail to see how it actually answers your question. Why not just stick with an alias?

Comment: The behavior of the two commands is not exactly the same. I think the one with the dash in it is intended for a smoother transition, and, to me, it seems less hacky than an alias for the moment. E.g. try `docker-compose --version` with the alias... it won't work.

Comment: This is because the `--version` flag is not supported in v.2. The alias does exactly what it's supposed to do - substitute `docker compose` with `docker-compose`. But of course it uses v.2 syntax all the way through. Why wouldn't you want this?

Comment: But hey, it's your system, so you should whatever you want. I just wouldn't recommend anyone else to use the method you describe here. 